# how to avoid repeating the same php functions

Tags: php, jquery

`index.php`

```
<?php
include ('db.php');  // db connections
include ('functions.php');  //  I need some functions
?>
```

The same php functions I need via jquery.ajax call.

```
$.post('functions.php', {vars}, function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

I'm getting error - `$db is not defined` because `$db.php` is not included in `functions.php`;

If I include `db.php` inside `functions.php` I'm getting error inside `index.php` - `$db is already declared`.

for now I repeat the same functions inside `functions.php` and an another file with `db.php` included, and I call it with `ajax`, but hope there is a more clever solution.

Comment: Include your db inside your functions.php, and only inside your functions.php. Use `require_once` on both includes, so it will always load only once.

Comment: It seems odd that you would be requesting `functions.php` directly via ajax.  Wouldn't that file only contain function definitions and not any directly-executed code?

Comment: you should use namespace to avoid collision of names

Comment: @PatrickQ,  `functions.php` gets some data from database, proccessed via js Is that odd?.

Comment: @aynber,  do you mean include `db` inside `functions` and `functions` inside `index` with `require_once`?

Comment: It would be odd for that file to contain any code outside of function definitions. The more expected behavior would be for you to request some other file (`getData.php` maybe) that calls a function that is _defined_ in `functions.php`.

Comment: @puerto That's correct. But I agree with Patrick Q, if functions.php and db.php are just helper functions, then it should not be called directly via ajax.

Comment: @PatrickQ, I understand but that's again some kind of repeating and duplicating. Everything I need is placed inside `functions.php`. Why is bad to call it directly?

Comment: You're going to need to provide more context (the actual code that you're using) to convince me that there'd be any sort of unnecessary duplication. What you _really_ should consider is moving to an MVC-style architecture, but I'm not going to ask you to rewrite your entire codebase.

Comment: Say for instance, functions.php contains `function test1(){ echo 'test1'; }  function test2(){ echo 'test2'; }  function test3(){ echo 'test3'; }`. If you call it directly, there's no code to actually use those functions. If you place the code to use those functions within the functions.php file (`if($test == true) test2();`), then that's going to be run on every page where you've included the functions.php.

Comment: @aynber, I see your point, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use require_once at first of  of your files, if a file already loaded so the require_once not load it again.